# Why is Prince considered a music genius?

Tags: pop, prince

Prince is often said to be a musical genius. No doubt he is a talent, but what are some things which really distinguish him compared to other pop musicians of his time?

Comment: My suggestion to find the reason is to look beyond the music he played  and his performances. He wrote a large number of popular songs that other artists made famous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prince was a phenomenal guitarist (which often gets overlooked), singer, songwriter and multi-instrumentalist.  He was also adept in a studio.  I took a tour of Paisley Park in Minneapolis after he passed, and he had 3 studios in his home.  It was told that he would often wake up in the middle of the night, write music, play all the instruments *and* record the songs all by himself, or sometimes with one person in the control room.  He was prolific, writing something like 80 albums worth of music in 40 years.  He also wrote songs for other artists, like Nothing Compares 2 U for Sinead O'Connor, and Manic Monday for The Bangles.  He toured, he wrote screenplays, he wrote soundtracks, he wrote albums, he wrote hits.  I'd definitely put him in an elite class of musicians who were consistently good, for a long period of time.

Comment: "he had 3 studios in his home" PP only became his home later on, originally it was a working studio where plenty of albums were recorded (FYC, REM,...) and some movies were filmed on the soundstage (e.g. Grumpy Old Men). Nothing Compares 2 U is a cover.

Answer (score 0):

Prince was an exceptional guitarist, as well as musical genius, singer, closer, song writer, performer, and actor. His fashion sense , his style, his originality, and his over all star quality , made him one of the greatest of all time.